# Change Circular Button Background and Text alternatively with button clicks

Tags: android, button, colors, background, background-color

I'm new to Android development & I'm stuck with this issue.

What I'm trying to do is

1. I'm trying to create a circular button with green background & red text on it.
2. Then I'm trying to change the circular button background to red and text on it to green.
3. Finally, Both these should repeat with button clicks. i.e., when I first click the button, 'green button with red text' should turn to 'red button with green text' and later when I click the button for second time the 'red button with green text' should turn back to 'green button with red text' and so on.

I successfully created a circular button & changed the button background, text on it. But, there was a complication.

When the button is clicked the circular button background changes to square and the complete square is filled with red. I don't want that.

I want the color to be filled in a circular way.

The below is an XML file from the drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#00FF00" />
```

The below is an XML from the layout

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="Activate"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:id="@+id/buttonActivate"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
```

The below is from the MainActivity

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {

    // Change the background color & text color of the button when clicked
    Button buttonActivate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonActivate);
    buttonActivate.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    buttonActivate.setText("De-Activate");
    buttonActivate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
}
```

Please elaborately explain how to do this since I'm new.

Comment: when you set background color its mean that you override background. You can create another drawable with red background and instead of the setBackgroundColor call setDrawable or like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00ff00" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Your onclick...

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if (buttonActivate.isSelected()) {
        buttonActivate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
        buttonActivate.setSelected(false);
    } else {
        buttonActivate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        buttonActivate.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The onButtonclick method you gave me created the loop I wanted. Thanks for that. 

But, when I open the App the activity is getting started with a Red button, I want it to be Green. Can you please look into that.

Comment: You can simply swap the two color values in the xml drawable, and likewise on the onButtonClick method.

Comment: That is what I was doing in the meantime. It worked. Thank You very Much for the help. **Advance Happy New Year** by the way.

Answer (score 0):

maintain the boolean variable i.e by default set boolean varable to  false and whenever click performed set true  and based on boolean variable set colors.